# How to access current module in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Let's say I have a module `MyApp.User` and it has the following method:

```
def update_some_counter(user) do
  from(u in MyApp.User , where: u.id == ^user.id)
  |> Repo.update_all(inc: [some_counter: 1])
end
```

Is there a way to change `MyApp.User` in the code above to some method that retrieves current module?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Patrick's answer is correct: you can use `__MODULE__`. However, I would advise all of your query functions in the model to receive the query as argument (see here: http://blog.drewolson.org/composable-queries-ecto/) and to not call the repository inside your model.

Leave the act of calling the repository, which is a side-effect, to the integration layer, like controllers and what not.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `__MODULE__`, which will be replaced with the name of the enclosing module at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the special form `__CALLER__` to access the name of the calling module.

Comment: This special form is only available inside macros.

Answer (score 0):

You can alias the enclosing module as well like:

```
defmodule MyApp.User
  alias MyApp.User
  ...
  some_function(User)
```

and then reference `User` directly. A shorthand for this is aliasing `__MODULE__` like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.User
  alias __MODULE__
  ...
  some_function(User)
```